# Can you use cd to go to a folder that isn't inclosed in the current folder?

Tags: terminal, directory, subdirectory, cd

for instance, if I had a folder, called folder `A`, and I was already inside folder `A`, and inside folder `A` there was a folder called folder `B`, could I do `cd B`, and then go back to folder `A` with `cd A`? Is there another method to do this? it hasn't worked when I've tried it, but maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: Use this to go up in the hierarchy:  cd ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't use `cd`  command with space, to return to the previous directory

Instead, you can just use `cd..` to return back to the previous directory

An example,

```
C:\Users\Monish Prasad V>cd Desktop

C:\Users\Monish Prasad V\Desktop>cd College

C:\Users\Monish Prasad V\Desktop\College>cd..

C:\Users\Monish Prasad V\Desktop>
```

I hope this solved your issue :)